# credssp: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 502

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-2.x, winrm, credssp

Seeing error `credssp: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 502`

Ansible is installed on Linux machine & I am trying to establish connection to Windows client machine

Have set below variables as per : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_winrm.html

```
ansible_user: <uname>
ansible_password: <pass>
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
```

Running playbook is resulting in below error. Could you give any pointers to check this further to get resolution on it?.

`fatal: [<hostname>]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "credssp: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 502", "unreachable": true}`

Adding details on client setup, which looks ok, following along : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_setup.html#winrm-listener

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Service "WinRM").Status
Running
```

Below indicates : **HTTP**: Enabled

```
PS C:\Temp\Ansible> .\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Verifying WinRM service.
VERBOSE: PS Remoting is already enabled.
VERBOSE: SSL listener is already active.
VERBOSE: Basic auth is already enabled.
VERBOSE: Firewall rule already exists to allow WinRM HTTPS.
VERBOSE: HTTP: Enabled | HTTPS: Disabled
VERBOSE: PS Remoting has been successfully configured for Ansible.
```

Exec policy set to **Unrestricted** as well.

```
PS C:\Temp\Ansible> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

Powershell version looks ok : 5.x :

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
```

And quick check on http link per below is working on windows client as well. Issue I am seeing only from Linux machine from which I am trying to connect/run playbook.

```
winrs -r:http://<hostname>:5985/wsman -u:<user> -p:<pass> ipconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume upon the chosen authentication method

```
ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
```

and the missing info about the CredSSP on the Windows side in the question and the 502 error, that this might be caused, because CredSSP ist not enabled.

As stated in the [Ansible WinRM Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_winrm.html#credssp) Documentation, if the selected authentication method is CredSSP, it needs to be enabled:

> CredSSP authentication is not enabled by default on a Windows host,
> but can be enabled by running the following in PowerShell:
>
> ```
> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force
> ```

According to the [WSMAN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/get-wsmancredssp?view=powershell-7.3) the state of the CredSSP can be checked  with:

```
Get-WSManCredSSP
```

Possible results:

> If the computer is configured for CredSSP, this is the output:
>
> ```
>  The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the
>  following target(s): wsman/server02.accounting.fabrikam.com
> ```
>
> If the computer is not configured for CredSSP, this is the output:
>
> `The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials.`

Comment: Yes `ansible_winrm_transport: credssp` set under defaults/main.yml under desired roles directory. I ran `Get-WSManCredSSP` and it's showing `The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials.
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.`. I also tried running on `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force` but no change in `Get-WSManCredSSP`. I did validated on client side, its all good atleast in terms of showing credssp set to true from some command o/p. I believe its something to do with ansible control machine credssp setup, but unsure.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that the user you are trying to connect with has admin rights on the remote computer.
If the user does, maybe it's a problem with the proxy.
I once had a similar problem and simply running this command on the remote server fixed it:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

you can read more about netsh here:

[WINHTTP - netsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Hope that helps, good luck !

Comment: Tried running as same admin user with which I am trying to connect from Ansible. But looks like, proxy is not set, as I get this `C:\Windows\system32>netsh winhttp reset proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).`